# How to get indexpath of customCell that has webview?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4, iostream

I am using the webView in customcell of tableview, webView covers total area of the customcell. When i click the web view in custom cell i can't get the indexpath. I have done the basic coding such as didSelectRosAtIndexPath.

Can anyone please tell me how to get the indexpath of a row when i tap the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell` ?

Comment: @demon9733-No, how to get indexpath using this function.

Comment: it returns the indexPath of your cell. Basically, if you are using `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, after you taped the cell, this selector will be called. And the second it's argument will be the indexPath of tapped cell.